# what type of sheet metal screws are harder than stainless steel?

Tags: repair, screws, dishwasher, stainless

I am trying to repair my dishwasher that has a stainless interior. I need to use stainless sheet metal screws so they wont corrode. I've got holes drilled and the screws go into the thin stainless just fine. The problem I'm having is that in the place I'm repairing the stainless is welded to a hard metal bracket. The stainless screws will not tap through the hard metal. The head just strips out trying. Here's a pic

[image]

I've tried drilling a bigger hole through the hard metal, but I can't control my drill that well. (I started with #4 screws, and through error and frustration I'm up to having to use #8 screws, which might stick up too far. This project is getting frustrating.)

Can I buy a harder screw to tap the treads through the hard steel then replace them with the stainless screws? If anybody has any other suggestions I'm open.

Comment: It sounds like what you need to do is drill and tap for a machine screw. I'm not sure they make harder self-drilling screws. IF they do, I've never seen them on McMaster Carr or similar fastener catalogs.

Comment: @BrownRedHawk I don't have any taps or I might try.

Comment: What kind of head do your screws have (flat/philips/torx/other)? Some type are far easier to strip than others.

Comment: @brhans Phillips.

Comment: I solved my problem! There's enough space between the stainless and the bracket that I was able to shove a really hard piece of steel between them and drill bigger holes in the bracket so the screws don't have to thread into it. Woo hoo!

Comment: I once heard a story that the original Phillips head was designed to slip in order to limit the torque which could be applied (cheap alternative to having to use a torque wrench ...) Something with a Torx or square head or perhaps a screw with a hex head suitable for a nut-driver would be much less likely to slip or strip.

Comment: @brhans I don't doubt that one bit. Phillips is a terrible standard. Beveled and pointed, it sure looks like it's designed to strip. I wish it would go away in favor of torx.